# Need help in performing CRUD operations on SharePoint provider hosted app using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, provider-hosted-app, azure

I have trial Azure subscription where i want to practice SharePoint Provider hosted app with it.

I am unable to find articles for CRUD operations on provider hosted app with MVC.

Infact, i want to do CRUD operation for each and every column type which includes MMS, People picker, Lookup etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated as i am totally new to this.

To be very straight forward i am looking for Code snippets or links or tutorial videos which can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could always refer to the basic [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) tutorial.

Here is a [nice video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yK5ZDc8gFY)

Comment: Thank You. I will check if this what i am looking for.